# What are acceptable copyright questions for this site?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There are only a handful of questions tagged "copyright." And there's no tag wiki.

[This](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18236/copyright-laws-about-commercials) questions was closed as off topic because it was about "legal." But since copyright is about the law, what constitutes an on-topic question about copyright?

Answer (score 3):

The problem there was that running a TV station has nothing to do with Video Production.  If it was wondering if you could use it in as a commercial playing on a TV in a movie, that would be on topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with none. Copyright, as you said, is about the legalities of what you can produce, and sometimes even what you can shoot. That is distinctly not about the art and skill of video production. It is administrative and tangential. I would further extend this to other legal restrictions that affect the industry. For example, drones holding cameras are falling under interesting laws today, but, again, that is an administrative concern, not really about the art and skill of video production.

Comment: Every time you point a camera at anything, you are touching some kind of legal issue. So, sorry to phrase it that way, but it's naive to think that the art and skill is everything you have to concern with. It is quite complex though because regulations are so different in different legislations so people should clearly point out to what legislation (geographically) they are referring to when asking a legal question.

Comment: @HansMeiser That's irrelevant. You can talk plainly about the art and skill of making a drone shot, but talking about when that's legal is a different thing and distinctly not about the art and skill of it. You said so yourself "you are *touching* some kind of legal issue." Touching = tangential. Tangential means: "hardly touching a matter; peripheral". Every SE has this conversation eventually. Drawing the line between the topic and tangential topics.

Comment: Well, if you say so. Art and craft still are executed in a system of laws and rules. If you shoot a doc and you are not getting permission from the people you shoot, there is a big chance the film can not be shown. So you can have all the discussion you want about how to best shoot an interview, if you don't follow some legal rules, you craft matters nothing.

Comment: Using copyrighted music is a common mistake people who are starting in the media business do. Fact is you can't just put any song you like in your work. At least not unless you have unlimited funds. So yes legal issues do matter a lot in video production and not just in the two examples mentioned here, it matters also in getting drone shots and other kind of things people might want to do for a film / video / media production.